# Emulating UITextView text rendering with CoreText?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextview, core-text

I'm attempting to create a TextView with the ability to highlight various words. I don't want to use the attributedText property in iOS 6 because I want to support iOS 5 and because of other issues (see here for example: [UITextView attributedText and syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543468/uitextview-attributedtext-and-syntax-highlighting)).

So the only option I've got is to use CoreText. I found this project: https://github.com/KayK/RegexHighlightView. What it basically does is overrides the drawRect method of the UITextView and draws the contents with CoreText. The problem is that the Core Text rendering is different from UITextView rendering - which leads the cursor to be in a wrong place (gets worse as the text gets longer).

Is there any hope to fix this issue? Maybe some other clever approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try EGOTextView. Or you can do the webView way. (UITextView actually does this under the hood mostly)

Comment: EGOTextView has many bugs and requieres serious work (I tried to use it but couldn't bring it close to the UITextView experience). The WebView option is something I hope to avoid, because it's way to complex for me...

Comment: Probably no more complex than CoreText. EGOTextView is fine, just not perfect. Most WebView implementations have their fair share of bugs too. The OMNI frameworks have a decent CoreText implementation too. You're not going to get out of this without some hard work. It's really hard to implement text layout.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an open source WebView implementation of a text view ?

Comment: Sure, it's been a very common paradigm up until iOS 6. Try this google search for: uiwebview text editor

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel
TTTAttributedLabel supports iOS 4.0 and higher.