# Replace part of UITextView's attributed text

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to create a text view in my app. It simply highlights the syntax and displays the highlighted text in a UITextView via AttributedText. Here's the code:

```
NSMutableString *ms = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:self.text];
[ms replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
self.attributedText = [syntaxHighlighter highlight:ms inRange:[self visibleRangeOfText]];
[self setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(range.location + text.length, 0)];
```

The problem is for large texts, it has to replace the whole text in 3rd line.
Is there a way to just replace a part of text without replacing the whole content?

Comment: This appears to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543468/uitextview-attributedtext-and-syntax-highlighting?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

UITextView implements `UITextInput` protocol.

If you want to replace a part of text without replacing the whole content, you can use method:

```
- (void)replaceRange:(UITextRange *)range withText:(NSString *)text;
```

But in some special case (when calling from other class), this method is not effective. I dont know why so I used:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.2;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
     //call method to change text of textView here...
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: The goal is to change the `attributedText`, not the `text`.

Comment: @rmaddy is right. This is helpful for replacing the plain text, but it will get rid of the formatting!