# How to get the rects from UITextRange in earlier iOS version than iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, range, cgrect, uitextrange

I wanna get the all rects from UITextRange. you know, if UITextView line wrap, the UITextRange will be represented by more than 1 CGRect. in iOS 6.0, there is a method as "selectionRectsForRange:", so you can get the all CGRects. But in older version, there is only a method "firstRectForRange:"
I checked the APIs documents again and again, but i find nothing.

My code likes blow:

```
UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;
UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];

//(in iOS 6.0)      
NSArray *array = [textView selectionRectsForRange:textRange];
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"rect array = %@", NSStringFromCGRect([[array objectAtIndex:i] rect]));
}
// (in earlier version)
CGRect rect = [textView firstRectForRange:textRange];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in this answer:
[How to find position or get rect of any word in textview and place buttons over that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313689/how-to-find-position-or-get-rect-of-any-word-in-textview-and-place-buttons-over/22637051#22637051)

You have to call `firstRectForRange` repeatedly.

When you get the *first* rect back you'll be able to check its range. Using this and the range you supplied originally, you can call `firstRectForRange` again with an adjusted range (if needed)...

Answer (score 0):

How about using frameOfTextRange and then do something like this . But I'am not sure if this works with your specific iOS version.

```
- (CGRect)frameOfTextRange:(NSRange)range inTextView:(UITextView *)textView
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
    UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
    CGRect rect = [textView firstRectForRange:textRange];
    return [textView convertRect:rect fromView:textView.textInputView];
}
```