# How to highlight text like in the image?

Tags: iphone, ios, search, highlight

How to highlight the text "cell phone" in the image?

[image]

**Updated**

I want to search text on a page and if found, the text should be highlighted in the way I have shown in the attached image.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Output**

[image: OutPut Image]

This [Regular Expressions tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet) has detail on how to search the desired text using regular expression on `UITextview` and how to highlight it.

Essential Code that is to be used:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self searchData];
}
```

1) Following code searches for the required pattern from the data i.e TextView:

```
 - (void) searchData
{


    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSString *pattern = @"Hello";  // pattern to search thee data either regular expression or word.
    NSString *string = self.textView.text;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:NSMatchingProgress ran     ge:range];
   [self highlightMatches:matches];
}
```

2) Here we highlight the matches obtained from the result of regular expression matching by making use of CALayer and label:

```
 - (void)highlightMatches:(NSArray *)matches
 {


      __block NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = self.textView.attributedText.mutableCopy;
     [matches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {

     if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSTextCheckingResult class]])
     {
         NSTextCheckingResult *match = (NSTextCheckingResult *)obj;
         CGRect rect = [self frameOfTextRange:match.range inTextView:self.textView];

         /** Shadow */

         CALayer *shadowLayer = [CALayer new];
         shadowLayer.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y-4, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
         shadowLayer.cornerRadius = 5;

         shadowLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
         shadowLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
         shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;
         shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
         shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 3;

         /** Label */
         UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y-4, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
         lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
         lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
         [lbl setText:[[mutableAttributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:match.range] string]];
         lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
         lbl.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

         /** Add Label and layer*/

         [self.view.layer addSublayer:shadowLayer];
         [self.view addSubview:lbl];  
      }
  }];

  }
```

Function used to obtain the frame of the matched text in the textView:

```
- (CGRect)frameOfTextRange:(NSRange)range inTextView:(UITextView *)textView
 {
    UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument; //Error=: request for member 'beginningOfDocument' in something not a structure or union

    UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
    UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
    CGRect rect = [textView firstRectForRange:textRange];  //Error: Invalid Intializer

    return [textView convertRect:rect fromView:textView.textInputView]; // Error: request for member 'textInputView' in something not a structure or union

 }
```

Comment: Could you please help me to get the CGRect from the match String?

Comment: With this method i believe it is not possible to get the CGRect of the matched Strings.

Comment: yeah I Know but i struggling with that I am not getting proper CGrect in my case origin is not coming proper and length and width is fine.Should I show the code?

Comment: using these two ans i found some but not exact what i what.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313689/how-to-find-position-or-get-rect-of-any-word-in-textview-and-place-buttons-over] and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126709/create-uitextrange-from-nsrange]

Comment: a kind of , but while searching the text giving me frame somewhere else not exactly on that.

Comment: Please send me discussion link? I am able to get that.

Comment: @VinayakKini, I ported your `frameOfTextRange:inTextView:` to Swift to use it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34050391/106435 Thanks for your answer here.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Thanks for letting me know. good that you ported it to swift can be helpful for many :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSMutableAttributedString` this might work for you.

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello";
NSMutableAttributedString *aString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString];
NSRange theRange = NSMakeRange(0,[aString length]);
```

> //Here we are setting foreground and background color to text for
>   highlighting it.

```
[aString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:17.5f] range:theRange];
[aString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor purpleColor] range:theRange];
[aString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:theRange];
```

> //You can change the range depending upon what portion of text you
>   want to highlight.

Comment: Your code is not Working even crashing though.I have fixed and pass this to a UIlabel but i can not see the change.Please suggest if i did wrong way?

Comment: I think u must have done something like this.

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
[myLabel setText:aString];

Instead of that set text as below
[myLabel setAttributedText:aString];

Hope it works..

Comment: Does this code give rounded corner background as shown in OP?

Answer (score 2):

for this you have to use `core Text` & for highlight you have to draw the text in `drawRect` method i.e. change in background color to yellow & increase the font size of text

[tutorial on coreText](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text)

Answer (score 2):

[There is a github repository "HighlightedWebView"](https://github.com/Kapeli/HighlightedWebView) that achieves virtually the same effect as you so desire.

[image]

> Drop-in WebView subclass that adds Safari-style in-page search-result highlighting.