# Border around every word of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Is there a way i can draw border around every word of `UILabel`. Suppose `UILabel` contains the string " This is the Line 1".

I want 5 different border around 5 words

> 1. This
> 2. Is
> 3. the
> 4. Line
> 5. 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners ?

Answer (score 10):

I am not aware of an easy to use code for UILabel, but for UITextView:

Swift playground

setup:

```
import UIKit

let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
textView.text = string
```

use regular expressions get a match for every word:

```
let pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex.matchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))
```

function to get a rect for each match (ported from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16828636/106435)):

```
func frameOfTextInRange(range:NSRange, inTextView textView:UITextView) -> CGRect {
    let beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument
    let start = textView.positionFromPosition(beginning, offset: range.location)!
    let end = textView.positionFromPosition(start, offset: range.length)!
    let textRange = textView.textRangeFromPosition(start, toPosition: end)!
    let rect = textView.firstRectForRange(textRange)
    return textView.convertRect(rect, fromView: textView)
}
```

iterate over each match, get its frame, use it to create a view for the background, add it to the text view:

```
for m in matches {
    let range = m.range
    let frame = frameOfTextInRange(range, inTextView: textView)
    let v = UIView(frame: frame)
    v.layer.borderWidth = 1
    v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    textView.addSubview(v)

}
```

[image: result]

---

But possibly this doesn't give the result you were expecting. To get a better controls, you could use attributed strings.

Here the same code with using attributed strings

```
import UIKit

let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.25
attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))

textView.attributedText = attributedString

let pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex.matchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))

func frameOfTextInRange(range:NSRange, inTextView textView:UITextView) -> CGRect {
    let beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument
    let start = textView.positionFromPosition(beginning, offset: range.location)!
    let end = textView.positionFromPosition(start, offset: range.length)!
    let textRange = textView.textRangeFromPosition(start, toPosition: end)!
    let rect = textView.firstRectForRange(textRange)
    return textView.convertRect(rect, fromView: textView)
}

for m in matches {
    let range = m.range
    var frame = frameOfTextInRange(range, inTextView: textView)
    frame = CGRectInset(frame, CGFloat(-1.2), CGFloat(2))
    frame = CGRectOffset(frame, CGFloat(0), CGFloat(2))
    let v = UIView(frame: frame)
    v.layer.borderWidth = 1
    v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    textView.addSubview(v)

}
```

[image: result]

---

Also helpful to create beautiful styles would be to add the views to a background view and add that textview on top

```
import UIKit

let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
let textViewBG = UIView(frame: textView.bounds)
textViewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.25
attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))
textView.attributedText = attributedString
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

let pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex.matchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))

func frameOfTextInRange(range:NSRange, inTextView textView:UITextView) -> CGRect {
    let beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument
    let start = textView.positionFromPosition(beginning, offset: range.location)!
    let end = textView.positionFromPosition(start, offset: range.length)!
    let textRange = textView.textRangeFromPosition(start, toPosition: end)!
    let rect = textView.firstRectForRange(textRange)
    return textView.convertRect(rect, fromView: textView)
}

for m in matches {
    let range = m.range
    var frame = frameOfTextInRange(range, inTextView: textView)
    frame = CGRectInset(frame, CGFloat(-1.2), CGFloat(2))
    frame = CGRectOffset(frame, CGFloat(0), CGFloat(2))
    let v = UIView(frame: frame)
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.66, saturation: 0.6, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    textViewBG.addSubview(v)

}
textViewBG.addSubview(textView)
```

[image]

---

to increase the space between the words we can alter the kerning of the whitespace

```
import UIKit

func frameOfTextInRange(range:NSRange, inTextView textView:UITextView) -> CGRect {
    let beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument
    let start = textView.positionFromPosition(beginning, offset: range.location)!
    let end = textView.positionFromPosition(start, offset: range.length)!
    let textRange = textView.textRangeFromPosition(start, toPosition: end)!
    let rect = textView.firstRectForRange(textRange)
    return textView.convertRect(rect, fromView: textView)
}

let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

textView.attributedText = {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.25
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s", options: [])
    let matches = regex.matchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))
    for m in matches {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 6, range: m.range)
    }
    return NSAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
}()

let textViewBG = UIView(frame: textView.bounds)
textViewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


let pattern = "[^ ]+"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex.matchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))

for m in matches {
    textViewBG.addSubview({
        let range = m.range
        var frame = frameOfTextInRange(range, inTextView: textView)
        frame = CGRectInset(frame, CGFloat(-3), CGFloat(2))
        frame = CGRectOffset(frame, CGFloat(0), CGFloat(3))
        let v = UIView(frame: frame)
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 211.0/360.0, saturation: 0.35, brightness: 0.78    , alpha: 1)
        return v
    }())
}

textViewBG.addSubview(textView)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Asked about `UIlabel` , answer about `UITextView` ?!

Comment: @TomSawyer: feel free to post a UILabel answer

Comment: Thanks for a thorough response, very helpful!

Comment: @vikingosegundo. Hello vikingosegundo , when i change y position the content is not displaying correct

Comment: @vikingosegundo. Please help me to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 4 Version** 




This is the swift 4 version of 
[vikingosegundo Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34050391/10019135)
using a UITextView including a few other tweaks including: 
 • list of words coming from an array 
 • Centering in the textView 
 • Adjustable word limit 
 • Custom font

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var array = [String]()

array = ["WORD1", "WORD2", "WORD3", "WORD4", "WORD4", "LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONGWORD", "WORD5"]

var stringarr = String()

for i in 0...(array.count-1) {

if array[i].count > 20 {
    let count = array[i].count
    let dropCount = count-20
    let dropCharacters = array[i].dropLast(dropCount)
    var shortenedWord = "\(dropCharacters)"
    shortenedWord = "\(shortenedWord)..."
    print(shortenedWord)
    array[i] = shortenedWord

    }
}

stringarr = array.joined(separator: " ")


func frameOfTextInRange(range:NSRange, inTextView textView:UITextView) -> CGRect {
    let beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument
    let start = textView.position(from: beginning, offset: range.location)
    let end = textView.position(from: start!, offset: range.length)
    let textRange = textView.textRange(from: start!, to: end!)
    let rect = textView.firstRect(for: textRange!)

    return textView.convert(rect, from: textView)
}

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 200))
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

let lineSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0

textView.attributedText = {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringarr)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.5
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
    attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringarr.count))
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringarr.count))
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 10.0)!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringarr.count))


let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s", options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: stringarr, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringarr.count))

for m in matches {
    attributedString.addAttribute(.kern, value: 6, range: m.range)
}

return NSAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
}()


textView.textAlignment = .center

let textViewBG = UIView(frame: textView.bounds)
textViewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let pattern = "[^ ]+"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
 let matches = regex.matches(in: stringarr, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringarr.count))

for m in matches {
textViewBG.addSubview({
    let range = m.range
    let frame = frameOfTextInRange(range: range, inTextView: textView).insetBy(dx: CGFloat(-2), dy: CGFloat(3)).offsetBy(dx: CGFloat(0), dy: CGFloat(3))
    let v = UIView(frame: frame)
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return v
    }())
}

textViewBG.addSubview(textView)

//: End of playground
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLGJi.png)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create one label for each word....do it programmatically! I did it now, test please! hope u enjoy :-)

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var arrayStrings = [String]()
var x : CGFloat = 0
var labelReference = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let space = " "
    let string = "This is the line 1"
    var word = string.componentsSeparatedByString(space)
    print (word[0]) // prints "This"
    print(word[1]) // print "is"

    for var i = 0; i < word.count ; i++ {


        arrayStrings.append(word[i])


        let characteresCount = word[i].characters.count


        // change de "9" based on your font size
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(32 + x), 30, CGFloat(characteresCount * 9), 25))
        x += label.frame.size.width + 2
        label.text = word[i]
        label.layer
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        view.addSubview(label)


      }

   }

}
```

Comment: This should only yield acceptable results for mono spaced fonts, such as courier, as otherwise the width of different glyph differ a lot, such as the with for an `i` and a `m`.

Comment: to fix this you could call `sizeToFit()` on each label

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5. Alternative solution**

The Solution Logic

1. Converting Strings to Labels
2. Customizing Labels
3. Converting Labels to Images
4. Converting Images to Attributed text
5. Creating TextView
6. Setting Attributed text to TextView

[image: Final TextView]

You can find implementation here:

https://github.com/vivatum/WordsAsTagLabels-Example