# Change font for decimal part of a number

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, fonts, nsnumberformatter

my question is, how do I change the font size for the decimal part of a number, example:

[image: Example]

So far I can separate the components of the number but I can't manage to find a solution to change the font size of the decimal part, here is what I currently have:

```
-(NSString *)formaterDecimale:(CGFloat)valeurReel{
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter =[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
[numberFormatter setNegativePrefix:@""];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
[numberFormatter setRoundingIncrement:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01]];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];

NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:valeurReel]];
return formattedString;
```

}

Best Regards.

Comment: You can't do it with `NSNumberFormatter` directly. You need to return an `NSAttributedString` that applies the appropriate fonts to the proper parts of the string.

Comment: BTW - what's the point of using `NSNumberFormatter` if you are going to hardcode the grouping and decimal separators? People in locale's that used different separators are not going to be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create attributed string

```
NSRange range = [formattedString rangeOfString:@"."];
range.length = formattedString.length - range.location;


NSDictionary *normalAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15],
                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor] };

NSDictionary *smallAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8],
                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor grayColor] };

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:formattedString attributes:normalAttributes];
[attributedString setAttributes:smallAttributes range:range];
```

and then assign it to `attributedText` property of UILabel for example.

```
UILabel *your_label; // do not forget to create and initialize it
your_label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Some other controls like UITextView also can show attributed strings.

May be this [CGRect for selected UITextRange adjustment for multiline text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362131/cgrect-for-selected-uitextrange-adjustment-for-multiline-text/22572201#22572201) answer could be also interesting for you.

Comment: This is a good start, but beware that it will not work with locales that use `,` as the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
-(NSString *)formaterDecimale:(CGFloat)valeurReel{
   NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter =[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
   [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
   [numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
   [numberFormatter setNegativePrefix:@""];
   [numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
   [numberFormatter setRoundingIncrement:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01]];
   [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];

   NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:valeurReel]];

   // Change font of decimal part
   NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:formattedString];
   NSDictionary *decimalAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:13] };
   NSRange* decimalRange = [formattedString rangeOfString:@"."];
   [attrString setAttributes:spacingAttributtes range:decimalRange];

   return attrString;
}
```

Use attributed text on `UILabel`