# How can I force a UITextField to only support lowercase characters?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I want to override the key pressed event to force that, even when a capital key is pressed, the resulting output is still lowercase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work (you should also set textfield.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone)

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField==_usernameTextfield || textField==_emailTextfield) {
        NSRange lowercaseCharRange;
        lowercaseCharRange = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]];

        if (lowercaseCharRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            // some uppercase chars where found, need to replace

            UITextPosition *beginning = textField.beginningOfDocument;
            UITextPosition *start = [textField positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
            // new cursor location after insert/paste/typing
            NSInteger cursorOffset = [textField offsetFromPosition:beginning toPosition:start] + string.length;

            // convert whole text to lowercase and update the textfield
            textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                                 withString:[string lowercaseString]];

            // now reposition the cursor
            UITextPosition *newCursorPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument offset:cursorOffset];
            UITextRange *newSelectedRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:newCursorPosition toPosition:newCursorPosition];
            [textField setSelectedTextRange:newSelectedRange];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i upvoted ur answer. but you should check this   accepted Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092182/uppercase-characters-in-uitextfield . you just need to textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                                 withString:[string lowercaseString]]; and return NO;

Answer (score 4):

Solution is to add a selector for `textFieldDidChange`:

```
[self addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And in the `textFieldDidChange` event, add the following:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField {
    textField.text = [textField.text lowercaseString];
}
```

Or you can use the Interface Builder `@IBAction` **Editing Changed**

Swift 2 version:

```
@IBAction func textChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    sender.text = sender.text?.lowercaseString
}
```

Comment: This is not the best approach. It would be better to implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method and update each change as it happens.

Comment: That only fires after the text appears in the box though, not pleasant UX.

Comment: My approach actually forces the lowercase as the user types.

Comment: Weird.. I was doing that before returning the BOOL and it wasn't updating. Post an answer if you like.

Comment: If you explicitly modify the text field in the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`, return `NO`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if the user enters a character in the middle of the text, it jumps the selection point to the end of the text.