# Typing always (force) lowercase or uppercase - iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How to force to type always lowercase or uppercase for some textfields in **swift** language?

[image: mixed lower and upper]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Force Textbox Input to Upper Case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027164/iphone-force-textbox-input-to-upper-case)

Comment: This solution if for swift language. Not for Objective-C.

Comment: accepted answer can be used in swift without troubles

Comment: this is valid question and i don't understand why this is down voted. It can be marked duplicate if its already asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should `return false` in `if block` because you already updated the *textfield*.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  if textField.isEqual(textFieldBodrum) {
     textFieldBodrum.text = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string.lowercaseString)
     return false
  } else if textField.isEqual(textFieldYalikavak) {
                textFieldYalikavak.text = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string.uppercaseString)
    return false
  }
   return true
}
```

If you don't want to affect other *textfields* you should `return true` end of the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange function`.

https://gist.github.com/fatihyildizhan/ac5f476aebd306b0580a1fa069f153a3

Comment: Swift 4.2 the method has been changed to: yourTextField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.lowercased())

Comment: The accepted answer worked but caused the unforeseen problem of the target method I added to .editingChanged not firing. The answer was to change anything uppercase to lowercase in a separate .editingChanged method. Look at @LeoDabus' answer here stackoverflow.com/a/54926833/4833705

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution is to set the text field's `autocapitalizationType` property to `.None` to default to lowercase input or `.AllCharacters` to default to uppercase input. The user can still use the shift key to change capitalization though.

Comment: You are right but I want to FORCE to typing lowercase or uppercase.