# Input lowercase letters to uppercase and vice-versa in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, lowercase

I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3. I am creating an app for iOS. How will I make inputted lowercase letters be automatically converted to uppercase letters in the text field and vice-versa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typing always (force) lowercase or uppercase - ios swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989028/typing-always-force-lowercase-or-uppercase-ios-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is OK but with some modifications. Tested on letters with diacritical marks. Tested with copy and paste text methods.

The following that says

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

must be like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

---

This applies only to one text field only. To force inputting in uppercase even when Shift key is locked or pressed down...

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.lowercased() == string {
        textField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.uppercased())
    } else {
        textField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.uppercased())
    }

    return false
}
```

Do not forget to insert the following inside "override func viewDidLoad()".

```
    textField.delegate = self
```

---

This applies to one text field only. To force inputting in lowercase even when Shift key is locked or pressed down...

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.lowercased() == string {
        textField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.lowercased())
    } else {
        textField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.lowercased())
    }

    return false
}
```

Do not forget to insert the following inside "override func viewDidLoad()".

```
    textField.delegate = self
```

---

The following is for two text fields. Assuming one text field is always uppercase and the other one is always lowercase.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldAlwaysUppercase: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textFieldAlwaysLowercase: UITextField!

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.isEqual(textFieldAlwaysUppercase) {
        textFieldAlwaysUppercase.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.uppercased())
        return false
    } else if textField.isEqual(textFieldAlwaysLowercase) {
        textFieldAlwaysLowercase.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.lowercased())
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Do not forget to insert the following inside "override func viewDidLoad()".

```
    textFieldAlwaysUppercase.delegate = self
    textFieldAlwaysLowercase.delegate = self
```