# iOS -Textfield's shouldChangeCharactersIn range is disabling .editingChanged's target method

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a textField that I disable capital letters by setting `.autocapitalizationType = .none` and in `shouldChangeCharactersIn range` I replace any capital letters with lowercased letters
by [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31989029/4833705).

Forcing only lowercase letters works fine but the target method I added to `.editingChanged` stopped working.

Why did `.editingChanged` stop working?

```
let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    return textField
}()

let userNameTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(printSomething), for: .editingChanged)
    return textField
}()

@objc func printSomething() {
    // as I type inside the usernameTextField this no longer prints
    print("something")
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // only change characters for username textfield
    if textField == userNameTextField {

        userNameTextField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.lowercased())
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: ok trying it now

Comment: still nothing and everything is inside the closure. It's odd because once I comment out shouldChangeChars... everything works fine wether I do everything inside the closure or viewDidLoad.

Comment: remove `if textField == usernameTextField {

        usernameTextField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.lowercased())
        return false
    }` from your shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Comment: And do all your capitalisation in real time inside editingChanged

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying, inside .editngChanged change the chars to lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your userNameTextField declaration. When you initialise it there is no `self`. You need to change its declaration to `lazy`:

```
lazy var userNameTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    return textField
}()
```

---

I would also remove the shouldChangeCharacters in range and do all your character manipulation inside editingChanged method:

```
@objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print(textField.text!)
    textField.text = textField.text!.lowercased()
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but it didn’t work. Everything worked fine with the constant declaration until I added the shouldChangeCharatets method.

Comment: I added the target to viewDidLoad after the delegate and it still doesn’t work.

Comment: you mean `userNameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(printSomething), for: .editingChanged)` declaring it normally? Try `the lazy var` approach as it is. It has to work.

Comment: hey thanks this worked. You can remove the first part of your answer about the closure (for clarity) because your .editingChanged method fixed it. Btw I think you should add your answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989028/typing-always-force-lowercase-or-uppercase-ios-swift/31989029#31989029 because it's a really easy fix and it prevents the unforeseen problem that I had. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @LanceSamaria. I rolled back your edits so people will understand why lazy was needed.

Comment: I added a link to your answer underneath the other lowercase question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see any link

Comment: I placed it under the question itself instead of the accepted answer. I just moved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989028/typing-always-force-lowercase-or-uppercase-ios-swift/31989029#31989029

Comment: @LanceSamaria I see. You can just paste a link to this answer in comments there.

Answer (score 1):

Change to return true

```
   if textField == userNameTextField {

        userNameTextField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string.lowercased())
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, it caused the letters to appear twice in the textField. Thanks for the try!